# image based object detection and segemntation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, object-detection

I am currently studying image processing and learning matlab for my project.
I needed to know that if there is any method to detect a car from traffic image or parking lot image and then segment it out from it.
I have googled a lot but mostly the content is video based and I dont know anything about image processing.

language prefered : MATLAB
I am supposed to do this on images only not videos.

Comment: I don't think than this is possible in matlab! Try more adequate instrument, or use simplest methods like lite video processing.

Comment: Your saying is a huge project and cannot be fit into a matlab functions. But there are many image processing functions that can be used for such purpose. You might search some example projects instead of simple function.

Comment: There is no magical method for this. But in case of parking spot, if camera is fixed u can probably know ahead all the positions of the parking spots in the camera/photo frame. This might be a good start for further processing.

Comment: I think Matlab can be an appropriate environment for this purpose. But you should first focus on the algorithm you want to use. you can start here- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation and google more for this issue. And, ask your lecturer for specific methods...

Comment: The basic steps are appropriate only if the car is visibly different from background (in that case thresholding makes things easier) most of the time I get a messed up image....

@Marcin I need to work on standard data set...so can you give me any link with those pics[parking areas with and without cars]

Comment: @Eddy_Em in video background subtraction is a good method but I need to do this on images only.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very difficult problem in general. I'd suggest the easier way is to constrain the problem as much as possible - control lighting, size orientation of cars to detect, no occlusions.

This constraining has been the philosophy image processing has followed up until recently. Now the trend is that instead of constraining your problem, obtain as a massive amount of example data to train a suppervised learning algorithm. In fact it's possible that you can use a pre-trained model that would let you detect cars as it has been suggested in a previous answer.

There has been recently massive progress in the area of object detection in images and here are a few of the state of the art approaches based on neural network based approaches:

- [OverFeat](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2901)
- Rich feature hierarchies for accurate object detection and semantic segmentation ([R-CNN paper](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2014/papers/Girshick_Rich_Feature_Hierarchies_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf))
- Spatial Pyramid Pooling in Deep Convolutional Networks for Visual Recognition ([paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4729))

Framework that you could use include:

- Caffe: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/
- Theano
- Torch

Answer (score 0):

You can use the detection by parts method:
http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rbg/latent/

It contains a trained model for "car" which you can use to detect cars, surround then with a bounding box and then extract them from the images.